# How to add another optional option to the "printglossary" command?

Tags: glossaries, multicol, key-value

I'm using the glossaries package to introduce my terms in my book. Now I want to add another option to the `printglossary` command named "column" as below:

```
‎‎‎\printglossary[‎‎column=X]‎% which X is 1 or 2
```

**Description:**
I want the `column=1` to be active by default, but when the user enters `column=2`, I want the output to be typeset as if the user uses the code below in the body:

```
\twocolumn
\printglossary
‎\onecolumn
```

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{maths}{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do in foo bar}}

\begin{document}
I'm talking about \gls{maths}. 
\printglossary[title=Special Terms]
\end{document}
```

Could you please help me add this option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `glossaries` package uses the [`xkeyval`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) package to define the key=value options. The key family used by `\printglossary` is called `printgloss`, so you can define a new key using any of the `xkeyval` commands, such as `\define@choicekey`. The difficulty is how to interface the option with `\printglossary`. The `\onecolumn` part after the glossary can be achieved by redefining `\glossarypostamble`. The `\twocolumn` part before `\printglossary` needs to be treated differently as `\glossarypreamble` comes after the title at which point it's too late to change the column layout. Instead, the `column=2` option could modify `\glossarysection` so that it first switches to two column mode and then prints the header.

In the MWE below I've used `\define@choicekey` to restrict the user's choices to just `column=1` or `column=2`. Any other value will cause an error.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}

\makeatletter

\let\orgglossarysection\glossarysection
\newcommand*\twocolumnglossarysection[2][\glossarytoctitle]{%
  \twocolumn
  \orgglossarysection[#1]{#2}%
}

\define@choicekey{printgloss}{column}[\val\nr]{1,2}%
{%
  \ifcase\nr\relax
  % column=1
    \let\glossarysection\orgglossarysection
    \renewcommand*{\glossarypostamble}{}
  \or
  % column=2
    \let\glossarysection\twocolumnglossarysection
    \renewcommand*{\glossarypostamble}{\onecolumn}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{maths}{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do in foo bar}}

\begin{document}
I'm talking about \gls{maths}.

\printglossary[title=Special Terms,column=2]
\end{document}
```